# Copying size dimensions of one div and applying it to another div. Its adding the wrong size tho?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I could really use some help coming up with a solution to this problem.

I have a container with an image in it. The image has a red box shaddow so you can see its width and height. (see pic below)

And i have another set of empty containers with a red background color. I want the empty containers with the red background color to be the exact same size as the image. (see pic below)

## JS FIDDLE

Here's a full screen version: https://jsfiddle.net/nLv0xt52/2/embedded/result/

Here is my current script:

```
    var imgContainer = $(".mad-hat-parent-menu .quadmenu-product-float"),
    sourceImg = $("li#menu-item-15959 span.quadmenu-item-content");

    function resizeDiv() {
        imgContainer.height(sourceImg.width());
        imgContainer.width(sourceImg.width());
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
        $(window).on("load resize", function() {
            resizeDiv();
        });
    }, 0);
```

Currently the red boxes are not matching the size like how i need. ***This is really only apparent on 1920x1080 resolutions***.


[image]

Thanks!

Comment: image container height should be same as sourceimage height right ?

Comment: The image container also has text in it. By applying width value of the container to the red box height it creates the square i need.